# How can I make Entity Framework not create a class for some tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have several tables in my DB that I do not want EntityFramework to create classes for.  How can I tell EF to ignore certain tables?

I am not that familiar with configuring EF.  The way we tell EF to look at our DB and create/change POCOs is by running a Nuget command line of "Scaffold-DbContext "a connection string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -DataAnnotations -Force -OutputDir Data"

Is there a way to tell EF to ignore specific tables?

Comment: Have you tried EF Core Power Tools (disclaimer: I am the maintainer)

Comment: Sorry, due to the economy, I got let go from this project, so I didn't have time to try this.  Thank you for the comment, and everyone else for the answers.  Anyone hiring?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tables or schema switch to explicitly list which tables or schemas (include all tables within the schema) to reverse engineer.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which tables to include, using the -Tables parameter to specify the tables:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "connection-string" MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir dir -Tables table1,table2,table3
```